# How to get the difference in row from two table having same column in Hive

Tags: sql, database, join, hive, hiveql

What I am expecting is similar to the Diff checker. I have two tables: Table-1 and Table-2. Both of them have the same column. Table-1 has version 1 data, Table-2 has version 2 data. I need to find the places where my version 2 has changes when compared to version 1. Maybe an output where it shows only the columns that got changed along with the data would be really helpful.

Tried using

`SELECT * FROM Table-1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM Table-2`

The data is huge and it takes hours to run and moreover I have to check the diff manually post this. I believe there should be an efficient way to do this.

**Table 1:**

| id | name | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | person1 | person1@mail.com |
| 2 | person2 | person2@mail.com |

**Table 2:**

| id | name | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | person4 | person4@mail.com |
| 2 | person2 | person2@mail.com |

**Expected Output:**

name field changed in table 2. So I wanted something like the below output and that should help to understand that the values have been changed for id 1 in column name and email.

| id | name | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | person1 | person1@mail.com |
| 1 | person4 | person4@mail.com |

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Doesn't seem like Hive SQL supports minus or except. I think your best bet is to use a full outer join on all the columns and then look at the nulls on each side. You might want to handle nulls before the join though

Comment: @GordonLinoff Added the example scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your desired output, you can use `self join` on the condition of matching `id` but different `name` and `email`. And then `union` columns from each table.

```
select b.*
from t1 a
join t2 b on a.id=b.id and (a.email<>b.email or a.name<>b.name)
union 
select a.*
from t1 a
join t2 b on a.id=b.id and (a.email<>b.email or a.name<>b.name);
```

If I were you, I would have the comparison side by side

```
select a.id, 
       a.name as v1_name, 
       b.name as v2_name, 
       a.email as v1_email, 
       b.email as v2_email
from t1 a
left join t2 b on a.id=b.id
where a.name<>b.name or a.email<>b.email;
```

[**DEMO**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jVv9ZFdb7jt3cPfQrxKrra/3)

Comment: thanks @phil-coulson this really helps.